# AWS Lambda SSE Implementation: Subsequent Calls Result in Internal Server Error without Error Logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, server-sent-events, openai-api

I'm trying to implement Server-Sent Events (SSE) in an AWS Lambda function to stream data from the OpenAI API to the client. The function works correctly when called for the first time, but subsequent calls from the client result in either successful execution or an internal server error without any corresponding error logs or catch block being triggered.

Here's a simplified version of my Lambda function code:

```js
import util from "util";
import stream from "stream";
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const { Readable } = stream;
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

export const handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(
  async (event, responseStream, _context) => {
    try {
      const { prompt } = JSON.parse(event.body ?? "[]");

      if (!prompt) throw new Error("No promt provided");
      if (!Array.isArray(prompt)) throw new Error("Prompt should be an array");

      const messages = [...system, ...prompt];

      const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion(
        {
          model: "gpt-4",
          temperature: 0.3,
          messages: messages,
          stream: true,
        },
        { responseType: "stream" }
      );

      completion.data.on("data", (data) => {
        if (!requestStream.ended) {
          const dataStr = data.toString(); // Convert buffer to string
          console.log("Data as string: ", dataStr);
          requestStream.push(dataStr);
        }
      });

      completion.data.on("end", () => {
        console.log("On End");
        requestStream.push(null); // Signal the end of the stream
        responseStream.end();
      });

      await pipeline(requestStream, responseStream);
      console.log("FINISHED!!!!!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (!requestStream.ended) {
        requestStream.push(
          JSON.stringify({ error: error.message, message: error.response })
        );
        requestStream.push(null); // Signal the end of the stream
      }
      try {
        await pipeline(requestStream, responseStream);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(
          "Error in pipelining request stream to response stream: ",
          error.message
        );
      }
      responseStream.end();
    }
  }
);
```

When the Lambda function works correctly, I can see the data chunks being processed in the logs, and the stream finishes correctly at the end. Here's an example of the logs:

```
2023-05-22T11:48:49.721+03:00   2023-05-22T08:48:49.721Z ca657ea8-528f-4d25-af4a-01019830a65f INFO Data as string: data: {...}
2023-05-22T11:48:49.916+03:00   2023-05-22T08:48:49.916Z ca657ea8-528f-4d25-af4a-01019830a65f INFO Data as string: data: {...}
2023-05-22T11:48:50.235+03:00   2023-05-22T08:48:50.235Z ca657ea8-528f-4d25-af4a-01019830a65f INFO Data as string: data: {...}
[...]
2023-05-22T11:48:59.151+03:00   2023-05-22T08:48:59.151Z ca657ea8-528f-4d25-af4a-01019830a65f INFO Data as string: data: {...}
2023-05-22T11:48:59.505+03:00   2023-05-22T08:48:59.505Z ca657ea8-528f-4d25-af4a-01019830a65f INFO On End
2023-05-22T11:48:59.507+03:00   2023-05-22T08:48:59.507Z ca657ea8-528f-4d25-af4a-01019830a65f INFO FINISHED!!!!!
```

However, when there's an internal server error, the function seems to finish instantly after receiving the first chunk of data, as shown in the logs:

```
2023-05-22T11:49:02.666+03:00   2023-05-22T08:49:02.666Z df610e4a-8690-4647-a35a-e60107cbcbac INFO Data as string: data: {...}
2023-05-22T11:49:02.667+03:00   2023-05-22T08:49:02.667Z df610e4a-8690-4647-a35a-e60107cbcbac **INFO FINISHED!!!!!**
2023-05-22T11:49:02.838+03:00   2023-05-22T08:49:02.838Z df610e4a-8690-4647-a35a-e60107cbcbac INFO Data as string: data: {...}
2023-05-22T11:49:03.020+03:00   2023-05-22T08:49:03.020Z df610e4a-8690-4647-a35a-e60107cbcbac INFO Data as string: data: {...}
2023-05-22T11:49:03.193+03:00   2023-05-22T08:49:03.193Z df610e4a-8690-4647-a35a-e60107cbcbac INFO Data as string: data: {...}
```

I've already tried adding a promise to wait for the stream to end, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints on how to solve this problem or how to debug the internal server error without any error logs.

Comment: What is `pipeline`, what is `requestStream`? Who is getting an internal server error, where?

Comment: Forgot to add the pipeline, edited the question. I get an internal server error when calling the function with postman, curl or my react-native client.